# MySQL Select rows where timestamp column between now and 10 minutes ago

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a timestamp column that auto updates on insert/update.

I want to get the rows that have been updated within the last 10 minutes.

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
     status
WHERE
     code='myCode'
AND
     'stamp_updated' 
     BETWEEN
     NOW()
     AND
     DATE_ADD(NOW() , INTERVAL - 10 MINUTE)
ORDER BY 
     stamp_updated DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM status
   WHERE code = 'myCode'
     AND `stamp_updated` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
                           AND NOW()
ORDER BY stamp_updated DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Order in the BETWEEN operator matters - you had it backwards.

Comment: for some reason I keep getting empty result sets even after I update the rows to have the current time.. could you review and see if maybe somethings missing?

Comment: @krio: These rows you're updating - is their `code` value set to "myCode"?

Comment: yes, I'm actually removing that and just using (for testing): SELECT *
    FROM status
   WHERE 'stamp_updated' BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 50 MINUTE)
                           AND NOW()

Comment: @krio: Ok, then is the `stamp_updated` defined as a DATETIME data type?  Mind posting in your question what you get when you run: `DESC status`?

Comment: The auto update timestamp wasn't correctly firing because the data was the same so no updates were actually occurring. Your code worked great, thank you!

Comment: For those of us who it wasn't immediately clear to, the correct order for BETWEEN is min then max. `SELECT * WHERE stamp_updated BETWEEN lower_bound AND upper_bound;`

Answer (score 7):

```
 ... 'stamp_updated' BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE AND NOW()  ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why you're using the between construct.  MySQL can use logical operators on dates, and usually significantly faster. I would use this:

```
select * 
  from status 
  where code='myCode' 
        and stamp_updated >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
  order by stamp_updated desc 
  limit 1;
```

Comment: for a similar query on my own db this was at least 10% faster then using between.