# WHERE datetime older than some time (eg. 15 minutes)

Tags: mysql

I was looking at:

[MySQL Select rows where timestamp column between now and 10 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480947/mysql-select-rows-where-timestamp-column-between-now-and-10-minutes-ago)

I have a col named `creation_date` holding a datetime stamp: `2013-09-10 11:06:42`

I would like to pull all records that are OLDER than 15 minutes using:

`WHERE creation_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)`

However the query always returns 0 results, even with items older then 15 minutes present in the database.

Comment: by using ">=" you are actually fetching those rows which are recorded within 15mintues back from NOW().

Answer (score 89, accepted):

older would be `WHERE creation_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)`

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways to achieve this with `INTERVAL`. I will present three:

first:

```
WHERE creation_date < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE )
```

second:

```
WHERE creation_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
```

third:

```
WHERE creation_date < NOW() + INTERVAL -15 MINUTE
```

[Inspirtion](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-interval/)

Answer (score 0):

I work with

```
WHERE creation_date < NOW() - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE
```

OR

```
WHERE creation_date < NOW() + INTERVAL '-15' MINUTE
```