# select query in mysql to select the data before 15 minutes in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table:

[image]

I want to select data with `res_time` within the past 15 minutes.  I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE res_time >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE).

SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE res_time between timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)) AND timestamp(NOW()).
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726873/where-datetime-older-than-15-minutes

Comment: Suppose time is now 12.30 then you only want to show data if id 21.Am i right ?

Comment: What is your problme with your queries?

Comment: your first query seems fine, share the issue exactly what you are facing.

Comment: query does'nt working yet ... i want a query return with a specific result ..

Comment: Suppose time is now 12.30 then i only want to show data  of exact 12:45.

Answer (score -1):

You could try below query.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE res_time >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Comment: thanks sir ... but it results me all the columns of table .. .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! And what does it do? How does it work? Please add explanation to make this answer more useful for future visitors. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PHP then you can do this

```
$beforeTime = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime("-15 minutes"));
$query = "select * from test where res_time >= '$beforeTime' " ;
```

If you want the pure SQL solution then follow other mentioned solutions.

Cheers !!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this if you are not using unix timestamp:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE res_time >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(res_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```