# How to select all records that are 10 minutes to timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have timestamps in a table order_onsite_interpreter column called `assg_real_timestamp`.

I need to get all rows where assg_real_timestamp is 10 minutes before assg_real_timestamp.

The logic is this: I get all rows that are 10 minutes before the session starts(session starts as shown with assg_real_timestamp) and then I send a push notification to the user on a ios app. 
So if 10 minutes or less are before the session starts i have to fetch the rows.

This is an example, where I stop. I suspect I have made the wrong query.

```
SELECT * 
WHERE scheduling_type IN ('get_call', 'conference_call') 
AND push_notification_sent = 0 AND is_phone = 1 
AND assg_real_timestamp <= now() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

Comment: Missing table name in query!! It would be `select * from TABLE..`

Comment: This condition is impossible (at least for a single row):   need to get all rows where assg_real_timestamp is 10 minutes before assg_real_timestamp.  Sample data and desired results would be helpful

Comment: I've updated my question. More: I have to fetch all rows from order_on_interpreter, where timestamp 'assg_real_timestamp' is within 10 minutes before now().

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get all rows with `assg_real_timestamp` with a value set in the past 10 minutes.

```
SELECT * FROM `<table_name>`
WHERE scheduling_type IN ('get_call', 'conference_call') 
AND push_notification_sent = 0 
AND is_phone = 1 
AND assg_real_timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND NOW()
```

Mysql: [DATE_SUB()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

See also: [MySQL Select rows where timestamp column between now and 10 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480947/mysql-select-rows-where-timestamp-column-between-now-and-10-minutes-ago)

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone has to retrieve all rows from the database, by looking at a columns timestamp that's in GMT, where the timestamp is less that 5 minutes from now()

```
SELECT orderID, scheduling_type, frm_lang, to_lang, customer_id, amount, 
 onsite_con_phone, assg_frm_date, assg_frm_st, timezone FROM 
`order_onsite_interpreter` WHERE scheduling_type IN ('conference_call', 
'get_call') AND push_notification_sent =0 AND is_phone =1 AND 
DATE_SUB(CONVERT_TZ(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(assg_frm_timestamp), '%Y-%c-%d 
%T:%f'), '-7:00', '-0:00'),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) BETWEEN CONVERT_TZ(DATE_SUB(NOW(),
INTERVAL 5 MINUTE), '-7:00', '-0:00') AND CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '-7:00', '-0:00')
```

-7:00 is where I need to convert from my server's timezones to GMT timezone. It's a matter of syncing my values to GMT and them i can compare the timestamp and now(). This works, like this:
A session starts at 02:03, meaning that in 02:03 - 00:05 = 01:58 the cron job that's fired every minute should retrieve the rows from order_onsite_interpreter table. After retrieving the row, I then send a push notification to user's app with message 'Your scheduled session is about start in 5 minutes, please login to the app'. And set push_notification_sent = 1 so the user doesn't receive the message anymore in the scope of the five minutes that the query from cron job finds.